# On a non-standard approach to the classification of conics?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

I've been introduced to a method of classifying conics but it's too cumbersome for me. I've discovered something that seems a little more promising on Eves' *Elementary Matrix Theory*:

> [image]

And then,taking the rank $\rho$ of the matrix:

> [image]

And then, using also the discriminant of the conic (from Aarts' *Plane and Solid Geometry*):

> [image]

But I'm a little unsafe about using them. I mean, what could possibly go wrong against the usual approach of using rotations and translations? What would I lose by using this approach?

From what I know, the only problem that could happen is when the conic is an imaginary ellipse or hyperbola.

Comment: It's inaccurate to call this approach "non-standard". The matrix representation of conic section equations isn't even uncommon, although its introduction is usually delayed until students have a bit more sophistication. In any case, if all you want to do is **classify** a conic section from its equation, then "the usual approach of using rotations and translations" is over-kill; for instance, you don't need the position or axis-lengths of an ellipse to know that it *is* an ellipse. The matrix rank formulations help avoid that kind of distraction.

Comment: Thanks for a nice typo ! *classifying **comics*** is very good !! Cheers.